# How to pinch out in iOS simulator when map view is only a portion of the screen?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, simulator, pinchzoom

I have a view on the iPad that I'm adding an `MKMapView` to that is say half the height of the full screen.  However, when I try to pinch out on the iOS Simulator it doesn't work since the to nubs fill the entire iPad view on the simulator.

And so, with the map view half the screen and I press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key on the keyboard I cannot grab the map to pinch out.

Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

You can move the two gray circles that represent your fingers around the screen by holding <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> and moving the mouse.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! It took some practice to get it just right using two fingers from each hand but I have it working like a charm now.

Comment: Glad I could help, especially since it took me ages to discover this feature myself.

Comment: Option + Shift is also required for the gesture that changes the map tilt angle and triggers 3D mapviews.

Comment: In more recent versions of the iOS Simulator only the OPTION key needs to be held.

Comment: I needed  to update my preferences in accesibility to access this feature.

Comment: In windows compatible keyboard use Windows + ALT key and moving the mouse.

Comment: This method has a reference point set in the middle of screen, is it possible to define a custom reference point..?

Comment: For me just pressing alt key is enough.

Comment: @NoumanTahir You can, but it is very unintuitive. First you press and release OPTION + SHIFT which will make the gray circles stay on the screen without holding OPTION. Then hold down SHIFT to make the reference point follow the cursor.

Answer (score 55):

Try double tapping with the <kbd>option</kbd> key pressed. On the iPhone this causes the `MKMapView` to zoom out.

Comment: This did not work in my situation as one of the gray circles hovered over a table view on the bottom left causing the rows to be selected.

Comment: it only required one click for me

Answer (score 25):

Only pressing the alt key made the two gray dots representing your fingers appear for me...

Answer (score 17):

**2023 UPDATE**

**To zoom in**

<kbd>alt/option</kbd> + pinch in using mouse

> **Alternate option**: <kbd>control</kbd> + click (This will place a gray circle on the map, now you can click and drag your mouse to zoom in and out.
> If you want to disable it, just click on the circle again)

**To zoom out**

<kbd>alt/option</kbd> + pinch out using mouse

**To get flat view of the map**

Zoom to an area in map then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt/option</kbd> + click and drag mouse

Answer (score 10):

Double click, hold, drag finger.

Comment: Best way of all. All those circle things a not so intuitive

Answer (score 8):

**Updated Solution:**

Holding Option and Command gives you 2 finger vectors that spread out and in. Holding the mouse button down on the way in will pinch in and visa versa for spreading out.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Option (Alt) button or combination of Option button and command button along with mouse movement to zoom in and zoom out a map or an image.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to do this:

1- While holding the control key click with the mouse on where you would like to center the pinch gesture. This will cause one gray dot to remain on the screen. (Once its there, you can let go of the control key)

2- Now you can use the mouse to click and drag around the gray dot you specified in step 1

Once you are done you can remove the gray dot by tapping on it

Comment: This method is not working for me.  I get the gray dot but pinch in/out with my track pad has no effect. Tested iOS 9.3 iPhone 6s.

Comment: The pinch from your track pad won't work, you need to click and drag with the mouse.Think of the gray dot as one finger and the mouse as another.

Answer (score 2):

For Zooming in double tap using mouse.
For Zooming out press and hold on option/alt key this will give you 2 grey circles which represents your 2 fingers and drag your mouse up.
To Zoom in drag your mouse down with option key pressed(or double tap on mouse)