# UIPinchGestureRecognizer in UIView is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am trying to do zoom-in and zoom-out in a `UIView` using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. But when I do pinch on my trackpad, it is not recognising the pinch and the control is not going to my `twoFingerPinch` function. I am using the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//.......
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                      initWithTarget:self
                      action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)];
    [myview addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPinch];
//.....
}

- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
    if (recognizer.scale >1.0f && recognizer.scale < 2.5f) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale//);
        myview.transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Why it is not recognising the pinch from trackpad? Is there any other method to do the same?

Comment: is myView decalred in IB ?

Comment: Are you using option button for pinching gesture

Comment: @TejaNandamuri : Yes.

Comment: For zoomin/zoomout in Simulator you need to use the "option" key buttonalong with your trackpad for dragging.

Comment: Use `Alt` or `Option` key for pinch gesture instead of track pad.

Comment: @Raul : No. Why we need Option button to do pinch? Can't we do it directly from trackpad/mouse?

Comment: Try using `recognizer.scale >1` and `recogniser.scale<1` for zoom in and zoom out.

Answer (score 1):

First click on the Option button. you will get 2 gray spots which you can move using the mouse or trackpad. in older versions you need to press shift+option.

for more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622579/how-to-pinch-out-in-ios-simulator-when-map-view-is-only-a-portion-of-the-screen).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It was not the error in my code. I was not knowing about the use of Option button to do pinching.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `yes` for your `myview`,

```
 myview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```